# Bootstrap Modal Dialog CLICK Event dont works

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am facing an issue on bootstrap modal dialog,
and i have no clue on how to solve this.
When I implement 2 modal dialog on a site, the click event on either one modal dialog sometimes do fire it's event but sometimes not firing at all... I did place a breakpoint but anyhow it doesn't enter the break point when i click on the button ..

Comment: You need to provide your code. We have no clue how to solve this without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think both model some data is same. try it

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Large modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Large modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Small modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should not just consist of code, you should describe how it solves the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry i can't understand. please explain me.

Comment: Please describe how this solves "the click event on either one modal dialog sometimes do fire it's event but sometimes not firing at all". That's not a very clear description of the error, but as long as the question isn't any better, that's the question you have to answer. *Only showing code* that generates two model dialog boxes does not constitute an answer.